# Unable to submit tvOS app to store - Missing on-demand Game Center resources (ITMS-90547)

Tags: xcode, unity-game-engine, tvos

I've been (rather unsuccessfully) trying to package a tvOS app built with Unity 2018.3.

The app supports Game Center, and as required in the docs I've added the necessary Leaderboard images into an Asset Catalog within Xcode.

The app builds without issues, but fails at the last hurdle of trying to get it uploaded to the App Store:

```
ERROR ITMS-90547: "Missing On-Demand Resources. Your app contains Game Center content that is referencing missing on-demand resources."
```

I've been searching for solutions for a LONG time, but I seem to be the only person who has got this issue according to Google!

Here's some relevant background info:

- I'm **not** using On Demand Resources in the tvOS app - it's below the original 200MB limit (that shouldn't even matter anyway, as the limit is now 4GB). So I'm at a loss as to where it's seeing any On Demand Resources don't know where this is coming from.
- In the *Build Settings*, `Embed Asset Packs In Product Bundle` is set to **NO**. (I've also tried it on **YES** to no avail!)
- In the *Build Settings*, `Enable On Demand Resources` is set to **NO**.
- The Leaderboards all display correctly within Game Center view controller in the app.
- The Leaderboard assets all appear in the *Resource Tags* page of Xcode, in the `Download Only On Demand` group. Despite my best efforts I can't remove them from here.

None of the guides for tvOS or Game Center make any reference to any On-Demand Resources, so I'm at a complete loss.

If anyone has any pointers on anything I could be missing I'd be very grateful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a [tweet from a nice person](https://twitter.com/HELGEOHL_APPS/status/1107770826248634370) who also ran into this issue.

From what he says, the explanation seems to be that "*tvOS HAS to have this setting turned on because it loads Game Center leaderboards on demand whether you want it to or not.*"

So i recommend you try what he suggested:

1. turned off Game Center under capabilities for **all targets**
2. `Enable On Demand Resources` is set to **Yes**.

Optional: you can play around with the `Embed Asset Pack in Product Bundle` build setting as well.
Hope this helps for anyone stuck on this.

Comment: Thank you! Perfect solution, thanks for sharing :) I got a similar response from Apple Developer Technical Support that this wasn't their problem to look at :(... so I'll share this detail with them too - perhaps they can implement something which will help someone in the future.